# Cast List of Values as Table Definition

Tags: sql-server

I want to represent a list of values as a row of a particular table. Currently my code looks like this as part of an upsert:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.MyTable mt
  USING (VALUES(1234, 'Val1', GETDATE()))
         AS v(ID, Value, DateUpdated)
  ON v.ID = mt.ID
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT VALUES(v.ID, v.Value, v.DateUpdated)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET mt.Value = v.Value;
```

Ideally my code would look more like this:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.MyTable mt
  USING (VALUES(1234, 'Val1', GETDATE()))
         AS v(typeof(dbo.MyTable)) --TABLE DEFINITION, NO DUPLICATE TYPING
  ON v.ID = mt.ID
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT VALUES(v.ID, v.Value, v.DateUpdated)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET mt.Value = v.Value;
```

Where "typeof" allows the definition of my table to be used for both value type casting and name casting.

Comment: In a word....huh? You can't just replace a table name for a list of columns in a table constructor. That isn't how that works.

Comment: This works in other databases like Postgres, you are able to cast a list of values into a table "type".

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.  Specifically, it's unclear what `AS v(dbo.MyTable%ROWTYPE)` is supposed to mean because 1) we don't know what you intend the `%` operator to be (it's not valid in either ISO SQL, or in T-SQL), 2) There's no such thing as a rowtype in SQL, tables only have one type of row each, and 3) What's being specified in this clause isn't a rowtype nor a table, it's a column set which must be a subset of the previously specified table's columns.

Comment: If what you are asking is "*Can I dynamically specify which columns to use?*" the answer is : No, except for Dynamic SQL.  Which works, but is messy, complicated, can introduce security issues if not done exactly right and is definitely not for the faint of heart.  That said, I have done it quite a lot but it's still not clear what you would use it for in your example.

Comment: I don't know exactly why you'd need to do this, but a similar effect could be achieved by doing something like `SELECT * INTO #tmpMyTable FROM myTable WHERE 0 = 1; INSERT #tmpMyTable VALUES(list of values); MERGE INTO myTable mt USING #tmpMyTable v ON ...`

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why you are looking for "TABLE DEFINITION, NO DUPLICATE TYPING"

And I don't know if I have understood your requirement correctly.

Try this,

```
MERGE INTO dbo.MyTable mt
  USING (select  ID,  Value,  DateUpdated from dbo.MyTable%ROWTYPE where id=-1
        union all
        select 1234,'Val1',GETDATE()
        ) AS v 
  ON v.ID = mt.ID
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT VALUES(v.ID, v.Value, v.DateUpdated)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET mt.Value = v.Value;
```